# Force an existing user to sign-in with a specific account

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Similar to [Invoke "Verify it's you" authentication page from a Firebase application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220366/invoke-verify-its-you-authentication-page-from-a-firebase-application/47282318#47282318) use case, but my case differs in that the user is not logged in, but I want to force to log in as an existing user already registered in our app.

**Use case:** requiring an existing user that's just been invited to join a team to log in as given user (if she's currently logged out), or re-log as given user (if she's currently logged in to different account).

So, given either `user_id` or `email`, can I force the popup to preselect given account? We're using https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/, but passing the `login_hint`, as I understand it, won't help here:

```
signInOptions: [
    {
        provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        customParameters: {
            prompt: "select_account",
            login_hint: `some.existing.email@gmail.com`,
        }
    },
    firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
]
```

Even if it did, it would work only for google provider. Ideally, it should work for all providers.

Comment: `login_hint` works only for phone authentication. There is no way to preselect an email. In theory only Google supports passing a login hint on sign-in. GitHub and Facebook do not. So even if FirebaseUI supported passing the email, there is no way to pass that to Facebook or GitHub.

Comment: @bojeil Cannot FirebaseUI only allow to sign-in to given account if we supply existing firebase `user_id`? That should be entirely within its influence. The chooser allows to pick from user's various accounts (each have unique firebase `user_id`) So let's allow to pick only one single preferred account, if supplied.

Comment: No there is no way to sign in with a `uid`, not in FirebaseUI, nor in the underlying Firebase Auth library.

Comment: What I was trying to get at --- is it technically feasible and could be added to firebaseUI? Should a request ticket be opened, or PR made?

Comment: FirebaseUI cannot support anything that the underlying Firebase Auth SDK doesn't support. Signing in with uid is not a common feature. There is already a way to [lookup the email associated with a uid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) using the Firebase admin SDK.

Comment: I'm not talking about signing via `uid`.. I'm talking about FirebaseUI not allowing to pick an account other than the one identified either via `uid` or `email` (doesn't matter), that is supplied beforehand by developer (us), during init.